# ggplot: how to repeal the alphabetical order

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I'm using `ggplot2` in R

This is what my dataset looks like:

```
| Value | Big_condition | little_condition |
|-------|---------------|------------------|
| 10    | a             | A                |
| 12    | a             | B                |
| 11    | a             | A                |
| 6     | b             | B                |
| 10    | b             | B                |
| 8     | b             | A                |
| 9     | c             | B                |
```

That's my code:

```
#Thanks Jordo82 for this part    
dataset <- data.frame(Value = c(10,12,11,6,10,8,9),
                      Big_condition = letters[c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3)],
                      little_condition = LETTERS[c(1,2,1,2,2,1,2)])

# My ggplot code
p <- ggplot(data=dataset, aes(x=dataset$little_condition , y=dataset$value)) + 
  geom_boxplot() + 
  ylim(0, 20) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.2) + 
  facet_grid(cols=vars(dataset$big_condition))
```

Here is what I get :

[image: image from https://imgur.com/a/S3MGXst]

**I would like to reverse the order of the "little" conditions (B, A), and choose the order of the "big" conditions (for example c, a, b, e, f, d).**

How to do this?

thanks!

(this has nothing to do with it but I'm also looking for a way to display only the average value of my points, without the rest of the boxplot being displayed).

Comment: Refactor the variable with the desired ordering.

Answer (score 2):

To change the order in the plot, you have to reorder the factors.  As for your second question, to only plot the average values at each point, `summarise` the data first, then plot using `geom_point`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dataset <- data.frame(Value = c(10,12,11,6,10,8,9),
                      Big_condition = letters[c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3)],
                      little_condition = LETTERS[c(1,2,1,2,2,1,2)])

#calculate the average value for each combination of conditions
dataset_mean <- dataset %>% 
  group_by(Big_condition, little_condition) %>% 
  summarise(MeanValue = mean(Value))

dataset %>%
  #reorder the factors to control the order in which they are plotted
  mutate(Big_condition = factor(Big_condition, levels = c("c", "a", "b")),
         little_condition = factor(little_condition, levels = c("B", "A"))) %>% 
  #create the plot
  ggplot(aes(x=little_condition , y=Value)) + 
  #plot a point for all values
  geom_point() + 
  #plot a line for the mean of values
  geom_point(data = dataset_mean, aes(x=little_condition , y=MeanValue), 
            color = "red", size = 6, shape = 95) +
  ylim(0, 20) + 
  theme_classic() + 
  facet_grid(.~Big_condition)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you very much! 

I'm trying your solution (with all your code) but this is the first time I've seen %>% and R studio doesn't seem to like it. R tells me 
_"Error in dataset %>% mutate(Big_condition = factor(Big_condition, levels = c("c", : 
  impossible to find function "%>%"_

(For the second question, I actually want all my individual points plus a line for the average. )

Comment: Edited my answer to plot all points AND the average.  Make sure you install and load the `tidyverse` package to be able to use the piping operator `%>%`.  It's an incredibly useful tool, learn more here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/pipes.html